# Closed and unbounded sets

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to prove that if $cof(\kappa)=\omega$, then the intersection of two clubs doesn't have to be a club.

My idea is to make two sequences which would have empty intersection.

So by the definition of cofinality,

I can take sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n \in \omega}$ which is unbounded in $\kappa$ and then I was thinking of taking two subsequences, say $(\alpha_{2n})_{n \in \omega}$ and $(\alpha_{2n+1})_{n \in \omega}$ and if for $C$ and $D$ I take the set consisting of all $\alpha_{2n}$, resp. set of all $\alpha_{2n+1}$, again unboundedness is pretty much clear, but how can I prove closedness?

Comment: By closedness I mean: $C$ is closed in $κ$ if
$∀λ < κ (λ$ is a limit ordinal ∧ $C ∩λ$ is unbounded in $λ→λ ∈ C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intiutively, the reason $C$ and $D$ are closed is that they are "discrete" - their only possible limit point would be $\kappa$ itself. (This goes back to the picture I gave in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2154928/28111) to your previous question.)

This is informal, of course, but the idea is correct. Suppose $\lambda<\kappa$ is a limit cardinal; can $\lambda$ be a limit point of $C$? That is, can $C\cap\lambda$ possibly be unbounded in $\lambda$? (HINT: how big is $C\cap\lambda$?) What does this say about the closedness of $C$?